# Fetching data in intervals vs sse / websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-sent-events

I wanted to implement sse for notifications, so the user can get new notifications.
What is the downside of fetching that data in intervals in my frontend? Cant I just do that? Why is it common to use sse or websockets instead of fetching data periodically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is always a tradeoff between how often (and thus how much resource wastage, in this case of client and server CPU, client battery, and network traffic) vs. latency of noticing a notification.

I'd be annoyed if every one of the dozen tabs I have open was wasting CPU time and network traffic to contact some server every few seconds or minutes.  Minutes wouldn't to totally terrible, but it would mean the worst case latency for a notification to pop up would be minutes after the thing happened, unlike on Stack Overflow where comment notifications happen within a second or so.

From the server's PoV, it would potentially pile up a lot of traffic if everyone with the page open was making an HTTP request every few seconds, not just users that were actively clicking on things that needed server interaction.

Polling every second would be bad enough waiting for something locally; it would be ridiculous in a case like yours involving network traffic.  This is why we have event-driven methods of doing things all the way from low-level I/O (DMA + interrupts) to user-space socket APIs (`select`/`poll`) to GUI application to network stuff.

**Polling is the easy but ugly solution.**  Either amateur-hour or done as a fallback if no better API is available.  IDK if it would make sense to do it while prototyping before implementing the proper way in this case, or as a fallback, but it's not a good plan A.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)